# How to separate pytorch MNIST dataset into n subsets containing 2 classes each?

Tags: split, pytorch, dataset

I am trying to separate pytorch MNIST dataset into n subsets each containing data from only 2 classes and then save the n subsets in differents files to load them later.

For example, subset 0 will contain images of class 0 and 1 (corresponding to the MNIST classes),  subset 1 will contain images of class 1 and 2 and so on up to subset n.

If n is bigger than the number of classes several subsets will contain the same classes combination, ex: subset 10 can also contain images from class 0 and 1.

But every datapoint is given to only one subset, the same data point can not be in subset 0 and 10 for example.

I tried to write a code that does that using torch.utils.data.random_split and torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset but strangely in the files I save there always is the same data..

Thank you for your Help,